# can some one help explain for me about this part of the code, can't get it

Tags: swift

Why the last command:  anotherGrowBy500() = 2500 
I thought it suppose to = 2000. 
Any help will be appreciate.

```
func makeGrowTracker(forGrowth growth: Int) ->() -> Int {
    var totalGrowth = 0
    func growthTracker()->Int {
        totalGrowth += growth
        return totalGrowth
    }
    return growthTracker
} 

var currentPopulation = 5422
let growBy500 = makeGrowTracker(forGrowth: 500)
growBy500()  //500
growBy500()  //1000
growBy500()  // 1500
currentPopulation += growBy500()
let anotherGrowBy500 = growBy500

anotherGrowBy500()
```

Comment: growBy500 is called 5 times, why would you expect it to be 2000?

Comment: this goes to homework stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call `growBy500`, the number increases by 500.

Let's count how many times you have called `growBy500`:

```
var currentPopulation = 5422
let growBy500 = makeGrowTracker(forGrowth: 500)
growBy500()  //500               <-- 1
growBy500()  //1000              <-- 2
growBy500()  // 1500             <-- 3
currentPopulation += growBy500() <-- 4
let anotherGrowBy500 = growBy500 

anotherGrowBy500()               <-- 5
```

You called the method five times! 500 * 5 = 2500! That's why you get 2500.

The confusing part for you might be the fifth or the fourth call.

In the fourth call, although you are assigning things to `currentPopulatiion`, you are *still* calling the method!

*Whenever you see parentheses after a method, that method will be called!*

To understand the fifth call, you need to understand the line above it:

```
let anotherGrowBy500 = growBy500
```

You can think of this as creating an "alias" of `growBy500`. You're basically saying, whenever I call `anotherGrowBy500`, I'm actually calling `growBy500`.

Comment: thank you, I get it now, the fourth call is the problem, I didn't get it. I thought I just assigned the value currentPopulation = currentPopulation + growBy500()

Comment: @HarrisonTranLamBigini if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark